# .NET application hosted on Azure missing .cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an App service on Azure, if i look in the app service editor some of the code has `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="(Name of app).signupform.Default" %>` at the top, this was really confusing to me for awhile as it seemed the code was missing a huge part of the business logic that actually makes the app work. And i just found out that the CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" is what i was missing in this regards.

from a really early perspective of the code, i know this file has to exist somewhere in the azure service, the app just wouldnt be able to function otherwise, however the code itself is many commits ahead of these early parts of the code. My team and i basically just want to get a fresh copy of EVERYTHING that is in production so we can actually work on the product. but ive tried FTPing in, ive tried the App Service Editor, I cannot find these files that have a `.cs` tag.

can anyone point me in the right direction to find these files?

Comment: the .cs files are actually compiled into .dll files (inside the bin folder), this is why you cannot find them. I believe if you copy everything inside wwwroot, you should be able to move to another provider (if that is what you need).

Comment: Acutally i just downloaded everything in the wwwroot.. any idea where the .dll files would be contained? I would assume theyd be hosted at the same level as the relevant code. but ive not seen any kind of .dll files either.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio or rather i should say, the files inside the bin folder, arent viewable or usable.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio the biggest thing, is i need to be able to view and eventually make edits to this code. I inherited this code with no real testing environment to speak of and the reason i want a fresh copy of everything, is to setup a testing suite.

Comment: you cannot revert from compiled code to source code. Your previous developer needs to provide it from you. There are paid tools which will convert the main idea, but most of the time it won't be readable code as the compiler performs optimizations

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio not going to lie, the previous development team is a waste of time. Ive tried numerous times to get ahold of them, to ask them how they made changes to the production enviornments, repository locations and the like... to no real avail.. it seems ive inherited a DOA product

Comment: @JohnHanley Well upon my employment i made it clear which languages i was fluent in, .NET was not one of them, the management structure is pretty null, its just me and a senior developer as the development team, the owner bought the product from someone prior. and this is just what i inherited. its a good product and with some time though, i feel like we could rebuild it under relevant code that both me and my senior are fluent in, the problem is, as the product stands its hard to make changes that are necessary to kepe the product running. but we are rebuilding the service

Comment: @JohnHanley I just was hoping there might be a way to save a portion of this code as is.

Comment: .cs files are build as dll files, if you want to make any changes in the source modify , checkin ,rebuild and Publish the same code.          

Please refer [Decompilation of Source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/decompilation-of-c-code-made-easy-with-visual-studio/)